# Rust inline assembly template syntax

Tags: rust, inline-assembly

I have the following code in `test.s`:

```
call $8 + $8
```

Running `nasm test.s` compiles successfully. I'd expect the following equivalent Rust code to compile successfully, but it doesn't.

In `test.rs`:

```
#![feature(asm)]
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        asm! (
            "call $0 + $0"
            :
            : "i" (8)
            : "memory"
            : "volatile"
        )
    }
}
```

Output of `rustc test.rs`:

```
test.rs:4:9: 10:11 error: <inline asm>:1:12: error: invalid token in expression
        call $8 + $8
                  ^
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Or are you just experimenting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
#![feature(asm)]
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        asm!( "call ${0:c} + ${0:c}"
            :
            : "i"(8)
            : "memory"
            : "volatile"
        )
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant [documentation in the LLVM reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#asm-template-argument-modifiers). By looking at the output of `objdump`, we can verify that our inline assembly has been emitted:

```
0000000000005190 <_ZN4main20hc3048743ecd04f53eaaE>:
    5190:   e8 7b ae ff ff          callq  10 <_ZN10sys_common11thread_info11THREAD_INFO5__KEY20h20efb688859d2c0dRhsE+0x10>
    5195:   c3                      retq   
    5196:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    519d:   00 00 00
```

UPDATE: Here's an example of directly calling a function from inline assembly:

```
#![feature(asm)]

fn called_even_if_mangled() {
    println!("Just a regular function minding its own business");
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        asm!( "call ${0:c}"
            :
            : "i"(called_even_if_mangled)
            : "memory"
            : "volatile", "alignstack"
            // Omit "alignstack" and you'll get a segfault because of a
            // misaligned SSE load on some initialization code regarding
            // stdin.
        )
    }
}
```

But you should **never ever do such a thing**, unless you have a very good and compelling argument to do so (for example, because you're writing a JIT). I had to spend an hour debugging a mysterious segfault until I realized that I also had to put `alignstack` in the options section.

You have been warned.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea if it's possible to use this with symbolic names for inputs/outputs? I can't find any information on the topic, but [LLVM seems to support it](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/Sema/asm.c?view=markup)